# deobfuscating/decompiling extremely complicated javascript

Tags: decompilation, deobfuscation, javascript

I am working with some extremely complicated JavaScript. It is around 70,000 lines long and sections of the code look like this

```
U2xx.l11="0x78920d50";m2xx.r9G="11";b2xx.v3y="0x744ebc37";P2xx.K5h="0x4949db92";k4vv.k7Q=1099;k4vv.j6Q=255;C2xx.m6V=7035;f2xx.S7U="0x88f07878";v2xx.U0z="10991";h2xx.c0b="2665";U2xx.T11="0xd52da96f";I2xx.O2z="10410";v2xx.H2k="450";B2xx.L7n=0x88;E2xx.X4y="0xe8";j2xx.f4h="0xd36ebdd3";M2xx.o21="0x30fa5520";Z2xx.T4b="6325";F2xx.s4G="9036";G2xx.L2r=0xf46e5918;b2xx.X3y="0xe11ce5ed";h2xx.y0b="8843";Q2xx.H3Z=5152;b2xx.V7y="0xe89c636e";S2xx.v3b="6598";n2xx.E5y="0x00000000";K2xx.x90="0x7f456253";E2xx.J8y="0x88";i2xx.C70="0x30f3dcb2";Z2xx.X1b="6970";G2xx.z2r=0x171d121b;k2xx.e35=0x9c;Y2xx.s80="0x9d342e53";i2xx.j70="0x937c69d0";S2xx.a5b="3997";s2xx.l0t="5261";h2xx.C0b="3278";l2xx.a40="0x0f9357e7";
```

I know the Javascript is used to generate cookies to authenticate post requests sent to a web server just I am struggling to figure out how with the extremely obfuscated variable names and values.

Are there any tools that will help me reverse the hex values and present variables in a nice way? I have tried several tools like jsbeautify, jsnice and also Malzilla but to no effect.

I have posted some more code below if this helps provide more context

```
U2xx.l11="0x78920d50";m2xx.r9G="11";b2xx.v3y="0x744ebc37";P2xx.K5h="0x4949db92";k4vv.k7Q=1099;k4vv.j6Q=255;C2xx.m6V=7035;f2xx.S7U="0x88f07878";v2xx.U0z="10991";h2xx.c0b="2665";U2xx.T11="0xd52da96f";I2xx.O2z="10410";v2xx.H2k="450";B2xx.L7n=0x88;E2xx.X4y="0xe8";j2xx.f4h="0xd36ebdd3";M2xx.o21="0x30fa5520";Z2xx.T4b="6325";F2xx.s4G="9036";G2xx.L2r=0xf46e5918;b2xx.X3y="0xe11ce5ed";h2xx.y0b="8843";Q2xx.H3Z=5152;b2xx.V7y="0xe89c636e";S2xx.v3b="6598";n2xx.E5y="0x00000000";K2xx.x90="0x7f456253";E2xx.J8y="0x88";i2xx.C70="0x30f3dcb2";Z2xx.X1b="6970";G2xx.z2r=0x171d121b;k2xx.e35=0x9c;Y2xx.s80="0x9d342e53";i2xx.j70="0x937c69d0";S2xx.a5b="3997";s2xx.l0t="5261";h2xx.C0b="3278";l2xx.a40="0x0f9357e7";T2xx.v8U="0xd46a6abe";k4vv.R1Q=12;h2xx.Z0b="1877";W2xx.v25="10592";C2xx.t5V=8003;u2xx.J8r=0x133c89eb;i2xx.n70=0xd1c1d938;r2xx.f6U="0x3ddfe2e2";T2xx.R8U="0x81cdcd4c";M2xx.x81="0x082b94f9";G2xx.r7h="0xf8f813eb";g2xx.P0n="8406";m2xx.B0G="10723";G2xx.i2r=0x6ee89c63;v2xx.y3z="1856";G2xx.G7h="0x8e8e8907";M2xx.C21="0xb670d532";W2xx.F1k="8942";M2xx.d30="0xb3de080c";n2xx.h9y="0x7dce3ab4";n2xx.T5y="0x9357e70f";u2xx.D8r="0x766df6ad";c2xx.n2h="0x23654623";I2xx.A3G="1518";j2xx.p4h="0x4ed29c4e";E2xx.h4y="0x49";Q2xx.K1Z=3071;s2xx.T9X="4247";F2xx.Y2G="5246";S2xx.A3b="2091";U2xx.C41="0x1170ac1e";m2xx.T0G="65";v2xx.M4z="4129";k2xx.l2y="0x09";j2xx.O1h="0x61a3c261";B2xx.O2U="0x95c7c752";b2xx.b7y="0x119448fa";E2xx.k4y="0x62";v2xx.J4z="10974";k4vv.c3Q=1694;s2xx.o1t="2765";O2xx.s51="0x25f5024c";I2xx.C3G="3017";K2xx.M60="0x4c25f502";a2xx.f01="0xd2df599c";b2xx.x3y="0xef15e8e6";n2xx.Z9y="0xc920ac66";c2xx.F3U="0xc6844242";a2xx.B01="0x61c935b7";Z2xx.S1b="4646";i2xx.u50="0x198557f1";Z2xx.J4b="1";h2xx.s6b="887";F2xx.d2G="3715";G2xx.d3h=0x7c420fe9;T2xx.x1U="0x49a9a9e0";i2xx.K50="0xe70f9357";B2xx.h7n="4503";v2xx.P7z="4362";i2xx.L50="0x7e345bfb";K2xx.v60="0xa75051f4";I2xx.Q3G="5828";M2xx.s30="0x733f55f2";j2xx.l4h="0x0b1d160b";Z2xx.G0W=10338;g2xx.K2n="0xbccf0821";U2xx.G41="0x01269ff7";a2xx.O91=0xbb6bae84;K2xx.b60="0x58abacfa";n2xx.l9y="0xab73d323";B2xx.E3n=0x22;r2xx.v9U="0xd4984c4c";h2xx.Q0b="3534";Y2xx.k40="0xac1e1170";S2xx.c5b="5949";W2xx.L95="3660";E2xx.D2y=0x4c;r2xx.h6U="0x6a4c2626";u2xx.g8r="0xe67eaaff";S2xx.j5b="9122";B2xx.k2U="0x7e3f3f41";function m2xx(){}c2xx.l3U="0x7c84f87c";Q2xx.Z2V=5246;k4vv.T7Q=1190;P2xx.l5h=0x0a0a1e14;m2xx.c1G="3109";u2xx.W6r="4658";v2xx.D0z="72";M2xx.p21="0xe14fb6be";l2xx.C00="0x312a3f23";r2xx.C0U="0xaa5555ff";m2xx.K6G="8327";m2xx.h6G="631";F2xx.c2G="222";f2xx.z5U="0xe049a9a9";P2xx.r6h="0x1b1b2d36";j2xx.N4h="0xf407f3f4";v2xx.q7z="611";T2xx.X8U="0x70383848";o2xx.Z0y="0x54";function P2xx(){}F2xx.T4G="8772";K2xx.d60="0x3182e51a";c2xx.Y3U="0x63a5c663";r2xx.Z0U="0x50282878";u2xx.B3r="2074";I2xx.E2z="530";i2xx.B50="0xba0ae293";m2xx.j0G="4681";Z2xx.b1b="9055";j2xx.Q0h="0x42c68442";g2xx.b31=0xf75e2e39;C2xx.x7V=8122;c2xx.P8h="0xbcdf63bc";U2xx.K41="0x774b695a";B2xx.P7n=0x9f;M2xx.I21="0x275e963a";b2xx.l3y="0x764dd68d";U2xx.I11="0x494ec787";i2xx.p50="0x29768b43";S2xx.G7b="6532";g2xx.p2n="0x105633e9";E2xx.E4y=0x91;s2xx.r7X="2845";G2xx.H7h="0xe9e920c9";m2xx.O0G="3596";P2xx.b9h="0x3c3c4478";I2xx.X8z="2270";F2xx.a4G="7264";B2xx.W3n="0x45";r2xx.V0U=0xc98e4747;c2xx.j2h="0x2c74582c";k2xx.M35="0x30";C2xx.a2W=8918;U2xx.H11="0xffe67eaa";f2xx.E9U=0x6bbbd0d0;G2xx.c2r="0x640a0fd9";C2xx.T3V=8596;U2xx.F41=0xaed51e3d;m2xx.T6G="6469";Z2xx.G4b="562";r2xx.w9U="0x2cc1eded";O2xx.E51=0xaa4060ef;k4vv.n9Q=450;M2xx.W21="0x9d45f11f";u2xx.R7r="6825";O2xx.l51="0x3d96dd06";Q2xx.j8V=5834;o2xx.D1y="0x16";E2xx.r4y=0xea;g2xx.b8n="0xe9642247";c2xx.B3U="0x01030201";B2xx.h2U="0xe4727296";O2xx.H71="0x8af93e21";F2xx.S4G="9702";c2xx.m8h="0xd06bbbd0";B2xx.V5n="2734";v2xx.d7z="64";h2xx.e6b="1692";G2xx.N3h="0xc8ac993b";Z2xx.u1b="45";k2xx.Q2y="0x31";l2xx.s00="0x35b761c9";Y2xx.T20="0xd7c52acb";v2xx.v2k="2451";Z2xx.K1b="6832";n2xx.H9y="0x342e539d";k2xx.z35="0xcc";k2xx.D35="0x93";i2xx.h30="0xd81533a7";s2xx.z1t="2015";n2xx.u5y=0xe293ba0a;m2xx.X6G="8553";I2xx.k8z="9814";i2xx.F30=0xdaf741ec;P2xx.A9h="0x0c0c1418";j2xx.p8h="0x13352613";f2xx.M7U=0x90e07070;P2xx.S6h="0x31315362";b2xx.T3y="0x018c355d";l2xx.O10="0x26dab78e";a2xx.Z01="0x91f62f17";c2xx.G3U="0xca458fca";O2xx.u51="0x33e91056";G2xx.X7h="0x5555ffaa";O2xx.G51="0x7d854a24";S2xx.I3b="9418";P2xx.D0h="0xc0c05b9b";j2xx.b0h="0xf2f20dff";g2xx.t9n="871";M2xx.r21="0x4697a38d";K2xx.n90="0xc2032fb5";G2xx.U3h=0x51f4a750;v2xx.V7z="2912";E2xx.v8y="0x40";function C2xx(){}h2xx.Y6b="5232";O2xx.L91="0xe7038f5f";r2xx.h9U="0xbed46a6a";c2xx.h3U="0xda65bfbf";M2xx.V21="0x20ac66c9";s2xx.P9X="6648";C2xx.z5V=8088;G2xx.i7h="0x35355f6a";i2xx.f70="0xaff582c3";Z2xx.U1b="427";r2xx.d6U="0x68b9d1d1";l2xx.k00="0x0e7fcd50";f2xx.f9U="0xf3a25151";B2xx.q5n="1597";f2xx.Y7U="0xdd964b4b";m2xx.l1G="6966";I2xx.a5G="567";i2xx.I50="0x724e6c5a";k4vv.y1Q=9;O2xx.h51="0x5051f4a7";j2xx.n4h="0x143c2814";k4vv.Q7Q=1023;E2xx.K4y="0x37";M2xx.h81="0x7bf8b752";s2xx.A8t="6894";C2xx.V3V=8703;b2xx.x7y="0xb8e4f163";G2xx.Y2r=0xaedd3e05;m2xx.p0G="1921";r2xx.w6U="0x96e47272";Q2xx.h7Z=4582;u2xx.C6r="2576";c2xx.X3U="0xf00bfbf0";k4vv.o3Q=1541;F2xx.u8G="5712";K2xx.w50="0x5b38e719";s2xx.w8t=4294967296;v2xx.j1z="240";l2xx.m10="0xec0d8652";m2xx.e0G="8090";Y2xx.p80="0x51bd6e10";k2xx.N35=0x3f;W2xx.l0k="9685";C2xx.I9V=7436;T2xx.I4U="0x7a3d3d47";b2xx.O3y="0xc12c1fb8";o2xx.D0y=0x62;k4vv.m8Z=2268;c2xx.G2h="0x1b2d361b";a2xx.p01="0xe2250cbc";h2xx.b0b="8660";k2xx.n2y="0x27";a2xx.l61="0x73c737bf";s2xx.v44=function (){return typeof s2xx.M44.w2P==='function'?s2xx.M44.w2P.apply(s2xx.M44,arguments):s2xx.M44.w2P;};k4vv.h6Q=127;U2xx.w11=0xc1e3d077;P2xx.E9h="0x02020604";o2xx.P0y="0x67";m2xx.W0G="4616";U2xx.d81="0x420fe97c";T2xx.M8U="0xedfbfb16";K2xx.u90="0xec390b83";b2xx.C20="0xbce2250c";l2xx.I10=0xd077c1e3;l2xx.g00="0x2efb0b41";G2xx.C7h="0xe8e823cb";s2xx.g2t="3114";I2xx.H7G="4476";G2xx.p5h="0xeaea25cf";l2xx.x00="0xd629b07c";m2xx.T9G="6";K2xx.m90=0x6c8794de;m2xx.Q6G="8583";Z2xx.n0W=10221;M2xx.d21=0x6bae84bb;v2xx.j7z="6674";W2xx.Q9k="1798";b2xx.n3y=0x41ecdaf7;h2xx.W0b="6090";G2xx.I3h="0x90d8b8e8";a2xx.D61="0x1b9b919e";W2xx.C4k="5913";I2xx.P5G="10957";s2xx.l0g=function(){var E0g;return{v0g:function(){return E0g=!E0g;},m0g:function(){return Math&&typeof Math.random==='function'&&Math.random();}};}
```